# Having trouble mapping Sharepoint document library as a Network Place

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I am using Office 365, Sharepoint Online 2013. Using Internet Explorer these are the steps I have taken: ticked the keep me signed in on the portal.microsoftonline.com page.  It redirects me to Godaddy login page because Office 365 was purchased through them.  I have added these sites to trusted sites (as well as every page in the process) and chose auto logon in Internet explorer.  Once on the document library I open as explorer and copy the address as text.  I go to My Computer and right click to add a network place and paste in the document library address. It successfully adds the library as a network place 30% of the time.  I can do this same process 3 times in a row and it will fail the first 2 times and then succeeds.  It works for a little while and then I get an error that the DNS cannot be found.
I need multiple users in our organization to be able to access this document library as if it was a mapped network drive on our local network.  Is there an easier way to do this?  I may just sync using the One Drive app but thought that direct access to the files without worrying about users keeping their files synced.

Answer (score 0):

So there's essentially two options here. The supported, official and recommended method of course is to use OneDrive. If you try to speak with Microsoft I bet they'll probably just tell you to install OneDrive and call it resolved.

It is possible to map internet locations as Shared Drives (not just SharePoint files). So try the steps below in order and see if you have better luck.

1. Firstly, as you have done you'll need to sign in to the O365 portal and tick "remember" as you'll need to be authenticated. - Each user will have to do this mind.
2. Start **->** Right Click *Computer* **->** *Map Network Drive*
3. Select "*Connect to a Web site that you can store your documents and pictures*" link and proceed through the wizard.
4. Enter the site URL and continue through the wizard.

---

If you still experience problems add the below URL's to your trusted sites.

- https://*.outlook.com
- https://*.sharepoint.com
- https://*.microsoftonline.com
- https://*.lync.com

(Just taken from best practise trusted sites for O365 in general)

Answer (score 0):

You can automate the process of drive mapping to SharePoint Online with Powershell scripts. There are some scripts available in the community you can use and change to your needs. The scripts work by automating sign in through Internet Explorer and then using commands like net use to create a mapped drive.

- [OneDriveMapper](http://www.lieben.nu/numb3rs/?page_id=129)
- [office365drivemap.codeplex.com](http://office365drivemap.codeplex.com/)

Microsoft has a general troubleshooting guide to mapping drives to SharePoint Online here: [support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2616712](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2616712).

If you would consider a commercial solution for the drive mapping to OneDrive for Business, then you could take a look at Zee Drive which manages the mappings for you and also the authentication token renewal which if not done regularly, can cause drive mappings to be dropped: [Map network drives to OneDrive for Business and SharePoint Online document libraries - Reliably](http://www.thinkscape.com/Map-Network-Drives-To-Office-365-OneDrive/)

Disclosure: Zee Drive is a tool that my organisation develops